# Cannot setup Apache Spark 2.1.1 on Windows 10

Tags: java, python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed Apache Spark 2.1.1 on Windows 10, with Java 1.8 and Python version 3.6 Anaconda 4.3.1. I have also downloaded the winutils.exe and setup environment avriables for `JAVA_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME` as well as updated the path variable. I have also run `winutils.exe chmod -R 777 \tmp\hive`. But I am getting the below error when running pyspark in cmd prompt.

Please please can someone help, let me know if I missed out any important detail

Thanks in advance!

```
c:\Spark>bin\pyspark
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: **An error occurred while calling o22.sessionState.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':**
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
```

I still get errors when launching [spark-shell], but it looks like Spark launches since I get the 'Welcome to Spark' piece. The error I get is

```
C:\Spark>bin\spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/06/23 12:20:15 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
17/06/23 12:20:15 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
17/06/23 12:20:15 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:96)
... 47 elided
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode(NativeIO.java:524)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:478)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:532)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createPath(SessionState.java:639)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:561)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:188)
... 84 more
14: error: not found: value spark
   import spark.implicits._
          ^
14: error: not found: value spark
   import spark.sql
          ^
Welcome to
```

Comment: Do you also have an error when launching `spark-shell`, or is it specific to `pyspark`?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have updated my question, but yes it seems that [spark-shell] launches, but [pyspark] does not

Comment: _"it looks like Spark launches"_ >> don't assume too much, there is a nasty initialization exception. Did you check that the default SparkContext instance has been created, by simply typing `spark` and checking that there is an actual object reference?

Comment: That error stack is kind of useless; I assume it is truncated -- are there any **_"caused by"_** lines below??

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, I am extremely new at this, and must admit that I do not know how to check for a existence of SparkContext instance, where should I check for that? When typing spark in cmd I get that it is not a recognised command

Comment: Launch `spark-shell` and when the init phase is over and you get a prompt, type `spark` so that the Spark shell evaluates the expression => syntaxically, a single word can only be an object name that you want to inspect

Comment: Thanks for that @SamsonScharfrichter. When running `spark` after launching spark-shell I get an error `error: not found: value spark
       spark`

Comment: ...which means that you have *exactly* the same error in `spark-shell` and `pyspark`. The error handling is different, that's all. And the root cause is `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V` which might be related to a version mismatch between the Hadoop run-time you have downloaded (`winutils.exe` and friends) and the Hadoop version that Spark expects.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter do you maybe know where can I get the latest `winutils.exe`? I have tried multiple versions but still get the same error

Comment: About the version of Spark that you have downloaded -- what version of Hadoop does it expect??? E.g. `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7` expects Hadoop 2.7

Comment: For Windows 64 bit, the closest you can find to an official build: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils  (from the HortonWorks guy who maintains the Kerberos code base)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter okay thanks, I downloaded the 2.7.7 winutils from that link and it still gives me the same error.. is there anything else it could be?

Comment: In addition to `HADOOP_HOME` env variable, did you set `PATH` (as suggested in https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html) so that Java finds the "native libs" i.e. the DLL in `bin` sub-dir? Personally I prefer to set `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` to `-Djava.library.path=C:/bla/bla/bin` which is more explicit, and consistent with Linux.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, From the link provided, I do have the HADOOP_HOME and path variables updated to point to where the winutils.exe is saved. Do I need to add a Java variable? I currently have path variables pointing to `C:\Java\jre1.8.0_131` and `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup that worked for me is as follows "i didn't use winutils.exe":-
install pyspark and findspark using "Anaconda Command Prompt" as

```
pip3 install pyspark
```

and

```
pip3 install findspark
```

as you have already downloaded spark setup. unzip it and keep it in "C" drive i.e. "C:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7" and create new environment variable "SPARK_HOME" and set it to "C:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin" and open "path" variable in system variables and add the same there as well.
now open your command prompt and come from "C:\User*" to "C:\" by doing cd.. twice and run following command

```
set SPARK_HOME='spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7'
```

and you are good to go.
Now you just have to import the file location before importing pyspark in your jupyter notebook. use following code:-

```
import findspark
findspark.init('C:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark
```

Comment: Also make your JAVA_HOME env variable is set right.